# Scraping text with BeautifulSoup and Selenium doesn't me scrape from second tab (within the page)

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape [play-by-play score data](https://www.espn.com/nba/playbyplay/_/gameId/401474876) from ESPN for NBA. The data is slip by quarters, so I'm using Selenium to switch between the tabs/quarters, but it always scrapes the same data (the one for the first quarter). Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import requests

url = "https://www.espn.com/nba/playbyplay/_/gameId/401474876"

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

html_text = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "lxml")

minutes = list()
a_score = list()
b_score = list()

a_score_raw = soup.find_all("td", class_="playByPlay__score playByPlay__score--away tr Table__TD")
b_score_raw = soup.find_all("td", class_="playByPlay__score playByPlay__score--home tr Table__TD")
minutes_raw = soup.find_all("td", class_="playByPlay__time Table__TD")

for i in range(len(a_score_raw)):
    a_score.append(a_score_raw[i].text)
    b_score.append(b_score_raw[i].text)
    minutes.append(minutes_raw[i].text)

q2_xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div/section[2]/div/nav/ul/li[2]/button"
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, q2_xpath)))
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, value=q2_xpath).click()

a_score_raw = soup.find_all("td", class_="playByPlay__score playByPlay__score--away tr Table__TD")
b_score_raw = soup.find_all("td", class_="playByPlay__score playByPlay__score--home tr Table__TD")
minutes_raw = soup.find_all("td", class_="playByPlay__time Table__TD")

for i in range(len(a_score_raw)):
    a_score.append(a_score_raw[i].text)
    b_score.append(b_score_raw[i].text)
    minutes.append(minutes_raw[i].text)

q3_xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div/section[2]/div/nav/ul/li[4]/button"
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, q3_xpath)))
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, value=q3_xpath).click()

a_score_raw = soup.find_all("td", class_="playByPlay__score playByPlay__score--away tr Table__TD")
b_score_raw = soup.find_all("td", class_="playByPlay__score playByPlay__score--home tr Table__TD")
minutes_raw = soup.find_all("td", class_="playByPlay__time Table__TD")

for i in range(len(a_score_raw)):
    a_score.append(a_score_raw[i].text)
    b_score.append(b_score_raw[i].text)
    minutes.append(minutes_raw[i].text)

q4_xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div/section[2]/div/nav/ul/li[4]/button"
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, q4_xpath)))
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, value=q4_xpath).click()

a_score_raw = soup.find_all("td", class_="playByPlay__score playByPlay__score--away tr Table__TD")
b_score_raw = soup.find_all("td", class_="playByPlay__score playByPlay__score--home tr Table__TD")
minutes_raw = soup.find_all("td", class_="playByPlay__time Table__TD")

for i in range(len(a_score_raw)):
    a_score.append(a_score_raw[i].text)
    b_score.append(b_score_raw[i].text)
    minutes.append(minutes_raw[i].text)
```

Data for all quarters has the same tag and class and selenium is switching properly, so those shouldn't be an issue. What could be the issue? How can I switch tabs within a website to scrape? Feel free to point to an issue or suggest alternative solutions (or even free data sources for gameflow data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is embedded inside `<script>` on that page. To decode it you can use following script:

```py
import re
import json
import requests


url = "https://www.espn.com/nba/playbyplay/_/gameId/401474876"

data = requests.get(url).text
data = re.search(r"window\['__espnfitt__'\]=(\{.*\});", data).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)

for g in data["page"]["content"]["gamepackage"]["pbp"]["playGrps"]:
    for d in g:
        print(
            "{:<10} {:<5} {:<5} {}".format(
                d["clock"]["displayValue"],
                d["homeScore"],
                d["awayScore"],
                d["text"],
            )
        )
```

Prints:

```
...

2:05       100   111   Sandro Mamukelashvili turnover
1:51       100   111   Lindell Wigginton personal foul
1:42       100   113   Armoni Brooks makes 2-foot dunk (Chris Silva assists)
1:29       103   113   Lindell Wigginton makes 27-foot step back jumpshot
1:18       103   113   MarJon Beauchamp personal foul
1:18       103   114   Chris Silva makes free throw 1 of 2
1:18       103   115   Chris Silva makes free throw 2 of 2
1:03       103   115   Lindell Wigginton offensive foul
1:03       103   115   Lindell Wigginton turnover
50.5       103   115   Chris Silva bad pass (Lindell Wigginton steals)
45.8       106   115   AJ Green makes 28-foot three point shot (MarJon Beauchamp assists)
20.9       106   118   Vit Krejci makes 29-foot three point shot
5.9        109   118   AJ Green makes 28-foot three point jumper
0.0        109   118   End of the 4th Quarter
0.0        109   118   End of Game
```

---

EDIT: You can also parse the data with [`js2py`](https://pypi.org/project/Js2Py/) module:

```py
import js2py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.espn.com/nba/playbyplay/_/gameId/401474876"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

x = js2py.eval_js(soup.select("script")[2].text)
print(x.to_dict()["page"]["content"]["gamepackage"]["pbp"]["playGrps"])
```

Comment: Andrej, would it be possible to execute that script with js2py somehow within page context, and return the page html after that?

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus Never tried to execute *whole* page with js2py, but you could execute just the content of one `<script>`, where the `window['__espnfitt__']=...` is located and then read the `windows` variable back. If you want and have time you can post answer with js2py here, I'll upvote it :)

Comment: I tried with `f = js2py.eval_js("function $(" + r.text + ") {" + script_w_data.text + "}")` and then `result = f(r.text)` - got an error `JsException: SyntaxError: Line 2: Unexpected token <`. I don't think it's going to work, otherwise this would be a big step forward in web scraping.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus You have tried to pass the whole HTML to js2py? That won't work, surely. But executing only this one `<script>` might work (propably just setup `window` variable as empty dict before etc.)

Comment: With window setup as empty dict, the error I get is `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`. I don't think this would work. It would be some sort of what `requests_html` tried to be, and even they rely on pupeteer to execute javascript.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus I've updated my answer with `js2py` example.

Comment: Thank you for this example: I was trying to run the function (the actual script content) with an argument. + 1

Comment: I am still stuck with `js2py`, trying to execute the function with an argument (basically evaluate the script against a value in html). For example, `https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/2292550320967404` pulls a script from `https://journals.sagepub.com/cdn-cgi/scripts/5c5dd728/cloudflare-static/email-decode.min.js`, and it decodes value `91ebf9e9f7a8a2a1a5d1a0a3a7bff2fefc`. Is it possible to use JS2PY in this context? Thank you for taking the time to look at it.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus Yes, it's possible - you have to use Developer Tools -> Debugger and see what functions are called with what parameters and evaluate these functions with js2py. I've working demo figured out, so if you want you can create a new question here on SO (to not spam comment section :) and I post it there.

Comment: I'm just writing the question as we speak, Andrej, and wanted to ping you afterwards. Do you want a bounty as well? (I'm just asking, given you already have a huge score).

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus Not necessary - it's not hard question :)